# What is the MyBatis equivalent to the Ibatis update(String, Object, int) method?

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

There is [an update method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.0/api/org/springframework/orm/ibatis/SqlMapClientTemplate.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29) in iBatis `SqlMapClientTemplate` that allows to specify how many rows are expected to be updated (and throws exception if this is not matched).

Is there any equivalent to this method in MyBatis' `sqlSession`? [Those docs](http://www.ostools.net/uploads/apidocs/mybatis-3.1.1/org/apache/ibatis/session/SqlSession.html) suggest there isn't.

What is the best way to implement such a check the other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came back to that question and realized that it was really trivial.

[Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/orm/ibatis/SqlMapClientTemplate.java#385) of iBatis' overloaded `update` just calls the regular `update(String, Object)` and checks returned value.

As myBatis also has `update(String, Object)`, this can be simply implemented the same way.
Simplicity of this method was probably the reason to drop its support in myBatis.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such equivalent method in mybatis' spring extension

http://mybatis.github.io/spring/apidocs/reference/org/mybatis/spring/SqlSessionTemplate.html

Maybe you can raise it as an issue or submit as a pull request to the team :P

Comment: I have already read the docs. I'm looking for hints on how to achieve it the other way.